# get only exact matches in every object inside an array of objects with aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, search, aggregation

- my products collection in mongo db is like this:

```
Product {
  variations [
    {
      color,
      size
    }
  ]
 
}
```

- i have only one product:

```
{
  variations [
    {
      color: "Verde",
      size: "xxs"
    },
    {
      color: "Blu",
      size: "m"
    },
  ]
}
```

EXAMPLES:

- if i want the products that have color: "Verde" and size: "m" i should receive nothing
- if i want the products that have color: "Blu" and size: "xxs" i should receive nothing
- if i want the products that have color: "Verde" and size: "xxs" i should receive the product
- if i want the products that have color: "Blu" and size: "m" i should receive the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in general two options to achieve what you need in mongoDB and best suitable is to use the [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operation:

**Option 1: find/project**

```
db.collection.find({
variations: {
 "$elemMatch": {
  "color": "Verde",
  "lots.size": "xxs"
   }
 }
},
{
 variations: {
  "$elemMatch": {
    "color": "Verde",
    "lots.size": "xxs"
  }
 }
})
```

Explained:
This is the simplest option.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYgnyS5qk35)

**Option 2: aggregation/$match/$filter**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  variations: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "color": "Verde",
      "lots.size": "xxs"
    }
   }
  }
 },
 {
 "$project": {
  variations: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$variations",
      "as": "v",
      "cond": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$$v.color",
              "Verde"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$in": [
              "xxs",
              "$$v.lots.size"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:
In this option you much the conditions and you filter the matching elements via the aggregation framework.

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-6WGxAmpStH)